# Select tag to change selected option when user clicks on main nav using jQuery

Tags: jquery, haml

I'm trying to accomplish this

When the user clicks on the Ballasted Roof Mount link a drop down menu appears and they click on REQUEST A QUOTE and takes them to the REQUEST A QUOTE PAGE.

I want it so that when a user clicks on the request a quote link on BALLASTED ROOF MOUNT the select tag under PRODUCT TYPE changes to BALLASTED ROOF MOUNTING but for every page it automatically defaults to the first option which is ROOF MOUNT.

Can i use jQuery for this by passing in a parameter?

Heres my main nav code

```
     #ir_main_nav_container
  %ul#ir_main_nav
    %li
      = link_to 'Roof Mount', '/products/roofmounting/overview'
      %span.carrot
      %ul#rm_sub_menu
        %li= link_to 'Overview', '/products/roofmounting/overview'
        %li= link_to '360 View', '/products/roofmounting/360view'
        %li= link_to 'Tech Specs', '/products/roofmounting/techspecs'
        %li= link_to 'Support', '/products/roofmounting/systemsupport'
        %li.configure_btn= link_to raw("#{config_icon} Configure"), '/rm'
        %li.quote_btn= link_to raw("#{config_quote} Get a Quote"), '/support/requestaquote'
    %li
      = link_to 'Ballasted Roof Mount', '/products/ballastedroofmounting/overview'
      %span.carrot
      %ul#brm_sub_menu
        %li= link_to 'Overview', '/products/ballastedroofmounting/overview'
        %li= link_to '360 View', '/products/ballastedroofmounting/360view'
        %li= link_to 'Tech Specs', '/products/ballastedroofmounting/techspecs'
        %li= link_to 'Support', '/products/ballastedroofmounting/systemsupport'
        %li.configure_btn= link_to raw("#{config_icon} Configure"), '/brm'
        %li.quote_btn= link_to raw("#{config_quote} Get a Quote"), '/support/requestaquote'
    %li
      = link_to 'Ground Mount', '/products/groundmounting/overview'
      %span.carrot
      %ul#gm_sub_menu
        %li= link_to 'Overview', '/products/groundmounting/overview'
        %li= link_to '360 View', '/products/groundmounting/360view'
        %li= link_to 'Tech Specs', '/products/groundmounting/techspecs'
        %li= link_to 'Support', '/products/groundmounting/systemsupport'
        %li.configure_btn= link_to raw("#{config_icon} Configure"), '/sga'
        %li.quote_btn= link_to raw("#{config_quote} Get a Quote"), '/support/requestaquote'
    %li
      = link_to 'Pole Mount', '/products/polemounting/overview'
      %span.carrot
      %ul#pm_sub_menu
        %li= link_to 'Overview', '/products/polemounting/overview'
        %li= link_to '360 View', '/products/polemounting/360view'
        %li= link_to 'Tech Specs', '/products/polemounting/techspecs'
        %li= link_to 'Support', '/products/polemounting/systemsupport'
        %li.configure_btn= link_to raw("#{config_icon} Configure"), '/pm'
        %li.quote_btn= link_to raw("#{config_quote} Get a Quote"), '/support/requestaquote'
```

heres the code for the request a quote page

```
  <!-- container starts here -->
   <div id="container">

<br/>
<h1>GET A QUOTE</h1>
<div class="clear">&nbsp;</div>
<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" name="form1" id="form1" method="POST" target="_parent">

<input type=hidden name="oid" value="00DU0000000I430">

<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://www.ironridge.com">


<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="footer_form" style="float:left">

<label>Product Type</label>
<select  id="00NU0000001hkz3" name="00NU0000001hkz3"  class="txt_field" title="Application Type"><option value="Roof Mount">Roof Mount</option>

<option value="Ballasted Roof Mount">Ballasted Roof Mount</option>

<option value="Ground Mount">Ground Mount</option>

<option value="Pole Mount">Pole Mount</option>

</select> <br/> <br/>
```

I'm using HAML and HTML
 Thank you in advance for your input

heres a link to an image of what im talking about maybe it will help 
http://cmclove.org/Google%20Chrome1.png

Comment: I'm a little lost. You want to go from product page A where the user requested a quote, over to quote page b where the option they selected is automatically chosen?

Comment: The request a quote page is one page...so when a user clicks on the main nav links they get directed to the REQUEST A QUOTE page...but i want my select tag to change so that if they click on BALLASTED ROOF MOUNT the select tag will automatically change to BALLASTED ROOF MOUNT instead of the default first option ROOF MOUNT...

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of is a very rudimentary querystring implementation. So on page A, when the user clicks the link to quotePage.html, send them to quotePage.html?prod=BRM. Then, on quotePage.html, run something along the lines of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if(document.URL.indexOf("prod=BRM") !== -1){//if our url has our passed value
$('#00NU0000001hkz3 option:eq("Ballasted Roof Mount")').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
else
{
$('#00NU0000001hkz3 option:eq("Pole Mount")').attr('selected', 'selected');
}
});
```

(code is untested, but general logic is there)

Comment: heres a fiddle im working with http://jsfiddle.net/g4ymr/13/ so basically i want it so that when someone clicks on the link menu 2 the select tag will change to menu 2

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like i misunderstood what you wanted in my original answer. Corrections on your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/SxFtX/

HTML:

```
<a class="menuLink" href="">Menu 1</a>
<a class="menuLink" href="">Menu 2</a>
<a class="menuLink" href="">Menu 3</a>
<a class="menuLink" href="">Menu 4</a>

<select id="dd2" name="type1">
   <option value="1">Menu 1</option>
   <option value="2">Menu 2</option>
   <option value="2">Menu 3</option>
   <option value="2">Menu 4</option>
</select>
```

JS:

```
$('.menuLink').click(function() {
    var that = this;
    $('#dd2 option').each(function() {
        if (this.innerHTML === that.innerHTML) {
            $(this).attr('selected', 'selected')
        }
    });
});​
​
```